# Why code is maxing out the CPU while querying the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, ado.net

My C# code below checks a SQL database to see if a record matches a ClientID and a User Name.  If more than 15 or more matching records are found that match, the CPU on my Windows 2008 server peaks at about 78% while the 15 records are found while the below C# code executes.  The SQL Server 2008 database and software is located on another server so the problem is not with SQL Server spiking the CPU.  The problem is with my C# software that is executing the code below.  I can see my software executable that contains the C# code below spike to 78% while the database query is executed and the records are found.

Can someone please tell me if there is something wrong with my code that is causing the CPU to spike when 15 or more matching records are found?  Can you also please tell/show me how to optimize my code?

Update:  If it finds 10 records, the CPU only spikes at 2-3 percent.  It is only when it finds 15 or more records does the CPU spike at 78% for two to three seconds.

```
//ClientID[0] will contain a ClientID of 10 characters
//output[0] will contain a User Name
char[] trimChars = { ' ' };
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(string.Format(GlobalClass.SQLConnectionString, "History")))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT Count(*) FROM Filelist WHERE [ToAccountName] = '" + output[0] + @"'");
        command.Connection = connection;
        var rows = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
        if (rows >= 0)
        {
            command.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Filelist WHERE [ToAccountName] = '" + output[0] + @"'");
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Make sure ClientID does NOT exist in the ClientID field
                        if (reader["ClientID"].ToString().TrimEnd(trimChars).IndexOf(ClientID[0]) !=
                            -1)
                        {
                            //If we are here, then do something
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
            }
        }
        // Close the connection
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prepare for the hackers: lots of scope for SQL injection. Or, better, use parametrised queries.

Comment: This code runs on an internal system and it is not exposed to the outside internet.

Comment: For first,"using" is incapsulates disposal of disposable objects.Then you bring all data to client then checks them for ClientID. Why not `SELECT * FROM Filelist WHERE [ToAccountName] = @ToAccountName AND ClientID = @ClientID` ?

Comment: Additionally: `using` blocks clean up resources, you don't need to as well (ie. your `Connection.Dispose` is duplicating the `using` block).

Comment: @fraXis Most security breaches come from insiders. It is trivially easy to use parametrised queries, and safe. Just always use them: default to good practice. Additionally they can be quicker as well (the server can cache the query plan).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  But this wouldn't be causing the spike in CPU usage would it?

Comment: @Richard - Thanks.  I will use parametrised queries.

Comment: fyi dapper is pretty nice. `var listOfSomeClass = conn.Query<SomeClass>("SELECT * FROM Filelist WHERE [ToAccountName] = @account", new{account=output[0]});`. You can grab it with nuget. Nuget is packaged with visual studios 2012 but there is an installer/addon for 2010 and maybe older.

Comment: @acidzombie24 How would that affect the *server* performance? (Ie. completely irrelevant.)

Comment: is the CPU used in SQL or in your app, when the spike is occurring?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor The CPU is spiking on the server that is running my C# executable.  It is not spiking on the server that is running SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What is column type of `ToAccountName` please?

Comment: @fraXis thank you for your attention - please now, tell me, what is the code in the comment where you say //If we are here, then do something - do you have something there, or you are running it as it is, with this placeholder left blank

Comment: @Richard: It was just a suggestion which is why i made it a comment and not part of an answer. Less code and cleaner code is easier to debug. Also he said his performance problem was in C# not the server. Also he has app logic in the database read, if he used dapper it would be more obvious if it was populating the list in the query or his own app logic. So... theres many reasons however this isnt an exact answer.

Comment: Op this line looks weird. Cant you simply do `reader["ClientID"].ToString().IndexOf....` (is the tostring nessacary?) instead of  `if (reader["ClientID"].ToString().TrimEnd(trimChars).IndexOf(ClientID[0]) != -1)`. Look at my last comment, if you use dapper to pull the records out into a class does your CPU spike? You would then know if its the sql connection/driver or if its your app logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decrease the number of database access from 2 to 1 if will remove first query, it is not necessary.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT ClientID FROM dbo.Filelist WHERE ToAccountName = @param"; // note single column in select clause
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", output[0]); // note parameterized query

    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {  
        while (reader.Read()) // reader.HasRow is doubtfully necessary
        {
            // logic goes here
            // but it's better to perform it on data layer too

            // or return all clients first, then perform client-side logic
            yield return reader.GetString(0);
        }
    } // note that using block calls Dispose()/Close() automatically
}
```

Comment: This code means you are not performing string comparisons in your C# code and you will be retrieving less (possibly a lot less) rows locally. Neither of which explain the magic number '15', but the more performance bottlenecks you fix, the easier it will be to find the root cause.

Comment: @ElectricLlama: I fully support application server side calculations and or better to say business logic, and usually go this way. But don't be surprised that app server will require more (and more) resources. And from careful OP reading I found that this is his issue! Not DB server CPU usage spike but app server on DB request! (see his comments to the question itself)

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
SELECT * FROM Filelist
```

To this:

```
SELECT ClientID FROM Filelist
```

And check for performance.
I suspect there is a blob field on your select.
Also `select *` is not recommended, write your exact interested fields in your query.

Comment: I suspect you're right, I would definitely look at this if I was the fraXis. Unfortunately we don't know what is happening in the "do something" block :-)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing looks obviously CPU intensive, but one problem does stand out.

You are running a query to count how many records there are

```
"SELECT Count(*) FROM Filelist WHERE [ToAccountName] = '" + output[0] + @"'"
```

Then, if more than 0 is returned, you are running another query to get the data.

```
"SELECT * FROM Filelist WHERE [ToAccountName] = '" + output[0] + @"'"
```

This is redundant. Get rid of the first query, and just use the second one, checking to see if the reader has data. You can also get rid of the HasRows call and just do

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider what already said about parametrized queries.

Beside that, I think that the only big issue could arise in the following block:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Make sure ClientID does NOT exist in the ClientID field
    if (reader["ClientID"].ToString().TrimEnd(trimChars).IndexOf(ClientID[0]) != -1)
    {
        //If we are here, then do something
    }
}
```

So try to just cache your reader.Read() data in some local variable, releasing the SQL resources asap, then you can work on the data you just retrieved. Eg:

```
List<string> myRows = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
{
   myRows.Add(reader["ClientID"].ToString();
}
/// quit the using clause
/// now elaborate what you got in myRows
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the code to indicate a performance problem.

What does SQL Profiler show?

(Both in terms of query plan, and server resources used.)

Edit: To make this clearer: you have one measurement that *might* indicate an issue. You now need to measure more deeply to understand if it really is a problem, only you can do this (no one else has access to the hardware).

Comment: Would I run SQL Profiler on both the server running the C# code and the server running SQL Server 2008, or just the server running SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Would a 78 CPU spike be considered a performance problem though for finding such a small amount of records?

Comment: @fraXis 78% would be an issue on a 256 core monster server with matching UI and memory. On a single Atom core with limited RAM and the results not cached it may be normal.

Comment: Even on monster it depends. 78% is normal too if you scan 100TB database.

Comment: The database is very small.  Maybe only about 300 records total.

Comment: @fraXis: What hardware installed in SQL Server running server?

Comment: @abatishchev It is running on a Rackspace Server:  2.4ghz Quad Core AMD. 1 Gig of ram.

Comment: @fraXis: double check if there is a problem with the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you get a copy of [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from JetBrains.

At the very least, profiling the client code will help you identify/eliminate the source of the CPU spike.

Comment: @Richard: That's not what the OP said. The OP clearly states that the issue is with the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using parameters as suggested, however, I have seen performance problems where the type of the string column does not match the C# string. In these cases, I suggest specifying the type explicitly.

Like this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT ClientID FROM dbo.Filelist WHERE ToAccountName = @accountName"; 
command.Parameters.Add("@accountName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16, output[0]);
```

Or this:

```
SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add(
    "@accountName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param.Size = 16; //optional
param.Value = output[0];
```